# How can i use Navigator depending of the result of an async call?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I want to navigate depending on the return of an async call.

First, i used Navigator.push in a Future Builder snapshot.

```
FutureBuilder<String> fB = FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: func1(),  
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/index');
    } else if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
    return CircularProgressIndicator();//
  },
);
```

But i have error telling that the widget is built before his parent.

Then i tried to push depending on the result of FutureBuilder.

```
FutureBuilder<String> fB = FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: func1(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text("sucess");
    } else if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

if (test) Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: fB)); 
    else Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/index');

How can i know if it is success or not (what is the test) to provide the push ?

Comment: or use `WidgetsBinding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work with .then() methode.

```
FutureBuilder<String> fB = FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: func1().then((response) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/index');
    return response;
  }),  
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return null;
    } else if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```